# MongoDB | Dynamic-keyd objects of same shape

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to create a collection of certain form and I'm having trouble with it.

I would like to create an object, where *every property of it* is dynamic(i.e. key_1), yet the value of that property is an object of certain shape.

IMO the declaration should be something like this (*i ∈ N*):

```
{
  key_i:{
      phone: Number,
      name: String
  }
}
```

Creating shape premise for each sub-object;

Assuming I'm successful, my document will look like this:

```
{
  friends:{
     key_1:{
             phone: 123,
             name: "Davy"
            },
     key_2:{
             phone: 456,
             name: "Jones"
            }
      ...
  }
}
```

This way I can't tell the properties' name(key) before iterating it, yet I know what's the shape of any object in this collection.

Any clue of how this can be achieved?

Comment: why not use Array of Objects for this purpose ? if the documents are of same shape. That why you won't have to deal with dynamic properties.

Comment: Your alternative is legit. But, there will be two items, on each object that we'd like to keep under certain keys. the rest can be indiced